# Синхронизация записей баз данных

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Имеются 2 разные базы данных PostgreSQL, необходимо из pn базы таблицы MdDistrict вытащить id и name и сопоставить с pd базой таблицой District, если есть совпадения добавить pn_id в мою базу ну и если нет совпадений, то добавить запись с параметрами.Доступ к базе есть, получаю массив записей

```
md = MdDistrict.where(type_id: 2).select(:id).select(:name)
```

Как это можно сделать методом

Мне необходимо обновить записи в моей базе одно поле из другой таблицы, а если записи нет, то создать новую

Логика алгоритма , я получаю массив записей своей таблицы и таблицы откуда мне нужно сравнить записи

Это записи чужой таблицы

```
=> [#<MdSeparation id: 638, name: "№404", c_id: 36988>, #<MdSeparation id: 242, name: "№101", c_id: 36988>, #<MdSeparation id: 1114, name: "1", c_id: 1683919>, #<MdSeparation id: 294, name: "№911", c_id: 36988>, #<MdSeparation id: 55, name: "№1", c_id: 33683>]
```

Это я получаю записи своей таблицы

```
=> [#<Organization id: 244, name: "№103", lsd_organization_id: 36988>, #<Organization id: 246, name: "№105", lsd_organization_id: 36988>, #<Organization id: 247, name: "№106", lsd_organization_id: 36988>, #<Organization id: 248, name: "№107", lsd_organization_id: 36988>]
```

Мне необходимо сравнить записи и обновить свою таблицу данными из таблицы Separation. Сравнить как мне подсказали я могу, но как мне из массива сделать хэш, для сравнения и как мне понять к какой записи я обращаться буду. Или сравнивать массивы записей, но как так как запись элемента массива это

```
<Organization id: 244, name: "№103", lsd_organization_id: 36988>
```

даже использование в запросе lsd_organization_id as c_id вовсе убирает значение из массива.

UPDATE

Пошел по пути поиска записи в базе и обновлении её, если совпало поле name.

```
def self.find_lsd_sector_org
    MdDistrict.find_by_sql("SELECT md_separation.clinic_id , md_district.id, md_district.name, md_clinic.full_name
    FROM md_district
    JOIN md_separation ON md_separation.id = md_district.separation_id
    join md_clinic on md_clinic.id = md_separation.clinic_id
    WHERE md_district.type_id = 2").each do |f|          
            sector = Sector.where("lower (name) like lower (?)", "#{f.name}")
            if sector.present?
              sector.first.update_attributes(:lsd_id, f.id)
            else
              Sector.create(lsd_id: f.id, name: f.name)
            end
          end
        end
end
```

Плюс необходимо сравнивать еще по организации.

```
Organization.select(:lsd_organization_id).each do |g|
sector = Sector.where("lower (name) like lower (?) and lower (что поставить тут) like lower (?)", "#{f.name}", "#{f.???}")
```

В Organization.lsd_organization_id совпадает с таблицой md_separation.id, а Sector.organization_id=Organazation.id, как сделать еще одну проверку? как я пробовал, у меня выходит что Like не работает с целыми числами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно я не прав, с запросами и циклами, но на данный момент работает, но хотел бы выслушать комментарии и возможно другое решение

```
Organization.all.each do |org|
      MdClinicSeparation.find_by_sql("SELECT md_clinic_separation.clinic_id , md_clinic_district.id, md_clinic_district.name
FROM md_clinic_separation JOIN md_clinic_district ON md_clinic_district.separation_id = md_clinic_separation.id
 WHERE md_clinic_separation.name like '%Пед%' AND md_clinic_separation.clinic_id = #{org.lsd_organization_id} AND md_clinic_district.to_dt is NULL").each do |f|
        sec = Sector.where("lower(name) like lower(?)","#{f.name.strip}")
        if sec.present?
          sec.first.update_attribute(:lsd_sector_id, f.id)
        else
          Sector.create(lsd_sector_id: f.id, name: f.name, organization_id: org.id)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно все понял, то:

- Нужно использовать две группы моделей - родные модели от родной БД проекта лежат как лежали, а для моделей второй БД создать подкаталог и обернуть в модули.
- Далее в подкаталоге в файл *application_record.rb* добавить эту строку: `establish_connection :development_second_db`, где `development_second_db` лежит в файле *config/database.yml*.

Далее работаете с моделями. Например, так `Post.first` и `SecondDb::Post.first`.

Пример структуры каталогов:

- /app/models

  - /second_db

    - application_record.rb
    - остальные модели
  - application_record.rb
  - остальные модели

Пример моделей:

```
class SecondDb::ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection :development_second_db
    self.abstract_class = true
end

class SecondDb::Post < SecondDb::ApplicationRecord
    # ...
end
```

Comment: Модели есть, связи есть, я просто не совсем понимаю, как это реализовать, как массово проверить и обновить записи.

Comment: @an0mality прочитал то что вы дописали, но все равно мало что понял :) Если вы можете работать с данными обоих таблиц, то я не понимаю в чем проблема. Вы просто берете нужные вам данные из одной таблицы, далее берете нужные вам данные из второй таблицы. Делаете что вам нужно. И в конце записываете результат куда вам нужно.

Comment: возможно вы правы, но вопрос в том, что как мне например сравнить 2 хэша. Первый массив записей я получаю MdDistrict.where(type_id: 2).select("id, name") второй sector = Sector.select("lsd_id,name") как мне сравнить их, точнее если я использую lsd_id и просто id и как мне после добавить например записи, которых нет в моей но есть в другой

Comment: @an0mality если нужно иметь идентичные имена полей в выдаче, то это `lsd_id AS id`. Проверка, хм - это `if`; `district.take.id == sector.take.id`, но перед этим что-то типа `exists?` нужно использовать, или `find_by`.

Comment: Спасибо, завтра уже что-то попробую. сравнение хэшей хорошая идея.

Comment: чего я сегодня запутался опять. как я могу сравнить два массива, если я получаю целиком все записи сразу, и у меня значение элемента равняется <Organization id: 244, name: "№103", lsd_organization_id: 36988>, как мне сравнивать то их.

Comment: @an0mality как вариант - использование `.ids` и использование `.include?` в цикле.

Comment: дошел до простого сравнивания через like можете глянуть обновления и если придут какие нибудь мысли озвучить их. Я в RoR новичок, но стараюсь выносить для себя, что то новое